# Displaying Records based on priority in PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to develop faculty application with these fields:

```
 Name   Designation   Qualification   Experience
```

In this I have display records based on Designation,Qualification and Experience.

Example:

```
John Doe    Director       25      Phd

Jaison      Lecturer       10      BE
```

Comment: no..I am not sure how to proceed so wanted get some inputs ..

Comment: we cant expect others to code for you. first try to do it on your own.then if it doesnt work ask here.

Comment: how do you want to sort them? 2 of them are alphabetical.

Comment: how you have decide Priority? On basis of what ?

Comment: Wanted priority based on designation,qualification and experience.Director and principal details should be displayed at top and other lecturers details must be displayed according to these priorities.Ex: lecturer having Lecturer as designation , 5 years as experience and BE as qualification then while adding new record of another lecturer if he has higher experience ,qualification and designation this record must come above.

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a form following this model:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<select name="designation">
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
<select name="qualification">
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</form>
```

2)Create search.php and put something like:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(CREDENTIALS);
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE designation='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['designation'])."' AND qualification='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['qualification'])."' ORDER BY experience"));
//print results
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-
make a new table with ID and designation fields and assign ID according to their priority like

1-Director,

2-lecturer

and add a new colum to your original table which you can map with this table's ID field.
and then acces it order by id so that your higher designation will be shown first .

Answer (score -2):

If what you need is priority between fields, that is done with 'order by' in MySQL:

In your case:

```
select * from mytable order by Designation, Qualification,Experience
```

If you want to control if it is ascending or desdending:

```
select * from mytable order by Designation asc, Qualification desc, Experience asc
```

Keep in mind that the priority is marked by the order in wich you order the fields after the order by.

Also 'asc' stands for ascending, and 'desc' for descending.

Comment: the designation & qualification will be sorted alphabetically and it is not expected.

Comment: Will wait for him to answer that, may be he only wants priority between ordering fields and he DO want them alphabetically.

Comment: I dont want alphabetic sequence , I just wanted  priority based on designation,qualification and experience.Director and principal details should be displayed at top and other lecturers details must be displayed according to these priorities.Ex: lecturer having Lecturer as designation , 5 years as experience and BE as qualification then while adding new record of another lecturer if he has higher experience ,qualification and designation this record must come above.